# Number of permutations of $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ such that $|x_i-x_j|\ne|i-j|$ of every $i,j\in A$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> Let $B$ be the permutation of $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ such that $|x_i-x_j|\ne|i-j|$ of every $i,j\in A$ where $x_k$ is $k-th$ element of $B$. How many different $B$ exist?

On first sight it doesn't look too hard. Firstly, I tried to solve it like the following problem:
In how many ways numbers $1,2,3,\dots,n$ can be arranged in a row such that $k$ cannot be on $k-th$ place for all $k\in\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$? This second problem can be solved using inclusion/exclusion. Firstly, number of all permutation is $n!$. Now subtract the number of permutations where $1$ is on the first place, then where $2$ is on the second place etc. The number of these permutations is $\binom n 1 (n-1)!$. Then add permutations where we have $2$ incorrect numbers. This number will be $\binom n 2 (n-2)!$ etc. Final sum will be
$$f(n)=n!-\binom n 1 (n-1)!+\binom n 2 (n-2)!-\dots=n! \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}$$
I tried to solve the main problem using this method. My idea is to compute all permutations (it is $n!$), then for every incorrect pair of $i,j$ to subract these permutations, then to do it for $2$ pairs, then for $3$ pairs etc. I successfully did it for $1$ pair. I splited it in $n-1$ cases:
**Case $1$: $|i-j|=1$**
Numbers of ways to choose $(i,j)$: $n-1$ (it does not matter if $i>j$ or $j>i$ ebcause there is absolute value)
Number of ways to choose $(x_i,x_j)$: $2(n-1)$
**Case $2$: $|i-j|=2$**
Numbers of ways to choose $(i,j)$: $n-2$
Number of ways to choose $(x_i,x_j)$: $2(n-2)$
**Case $3$: $|i-j|=3$**
Numbers of ways to choose $(i,j)$: $n-3$
Number of ways to choose $(x_i,x_j)$: $2(n-3)$
$\vdots$
**Case $n-1$: $|i-j|=n-1$**
Numbers of ways to choose $(i,j)$: $1$
Number of ways to choose $(x_i,x_j)$: $2$
From this I computed number of permutations where at least one pair of numbers is incorrect (including overcounted permutations):
$\displaystyle S=\left((n-1)\cdot2(n-1)\right)\cdot\left((n-2)\cdot2(n-2)\right)\left((n-3)\cdot2(n-3)\right)\cdot{\dots}\cdot\left(1\cdot2)\right)\\
\displaystyle S=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k^2\\
\displaystyle S=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{3}$
Then I tried to do the same for $2$ pairs and then to $3$ pairs to find some regularity. It is very hard to find formula for $2$ pairs. Formula I've found is really complicated and I do not see any way to simplify it. For $3$ pairs I couldn't find any formula. I believe this problem isn't hard as it seems, so I think there must be an easy way to find solution. Is my way completely wrong or I'm close to solution, but I'm still missing something?

Comment: $f(1)=1,f(2)=0,f(3)=0,f(4)=2$, namely $(3,1,4,2)$ and $(2,4,1,3)$

Comment: @Michael I computed $f(x)$ for all $x\le30$, but it cannot help me to solve it.

Comment: Did you put it into the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences? (OEIS)

Comment: @Michael Of course, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Is there any pattern when $n$ is prime?  The ten solutions for $n=5$ all come from $i\to2i+m\pmod5$ and $i\to3i+m\pmod5$.  There will be at least 28 solutions for $n=7$ with similar formulas.

Comment: This is what I've found so far: for first few values of $n$ required function $f(n)$ will be $1, 0, 0, 2, 10, 4, 40, 92, 352, 724, 2680, 14200, 73712, 365596, 2279184, 14772512, 95815104, 666090624, 4968057848, 39029188884, 314666222712, 2691008701644, 24233937684440, 227514171973736, 2207893435808352, 22317699616364044$.

Comment: @Mathematician171 this is http://oeis.org/A000170

Comment: @Tad Yes, but I could't fint any formula there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to see that $f(n)$ is the number of configurations of $n$ mutually non-attacking queens on an $n\times n$ chessboard.  Given a permutation $\pi$ satisfying your conditions, place queens at the squares $(i,\pi(i))$.  They are non-attacking horizontally and vertically since $\pi$ is a permutation; the condition $|\pi(i)-\pi(j)|\ne |i-j|$ says precisely that the queens don't attack each other diagonally.

The $n$-queens problem has been very well studied - see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) for an overview; many references appear in the [OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A000170).  It's a safe bet that no general formula is known; in fact, the correct values appear to have only been computed up to $n=26$.